# How to move scene at top layer in ViewController?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, sprite-kit

I got a ImageView in my ViewController, but when I add a sprite scene using sprite kit in Xcode 5, it shows back to the ImageView.

In general, I want to change alpha for my emitter in my scene while shaking a phone, but I didn't find such method in sprite kit, thats why I want to add from scene just an emitter.

Thx for help!

Comment: Is there any reason why do you use `ImageView` instead of `SKSpriteNode`?

Comment: Yep, when I shake a phone the whole scene changing alpha, but I need only fire emitter to do this :(

Comment: Paste the code how do you change alpha

Comment: Nothing special :)
-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
        [skView setAlpha:(skView.alpha-0.1)];
    }
}

Comment: Судя по нику и так будет ясно :)
Я еще пробовал использовать синглтон, но его значение передается в сцену только 1 раз при запуске программы...

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to create a `SKSpriteNode` instead of `ImageView`. Then create `SKNode` and make it a parent of all of other nodes. After that you can change parent's alpha instead of changing alpha of `SKView`:

```
@interface GameScene()

@property SKSpriteNode *imageNode;
@property SKNode parentNode;

@end

@implementation GameScene

- (instancetype) initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        self.imageNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"yourImage"];
        [self addChild:self.imageNode];

        self.parentNode = [SKNode node];
        self.parentNode.zPosition = self.imageNode.zPosition + 1;
        [self addChild:self.parentNode];

        // Add other nodes
        [self.parentNode addChild:....];
    }
}

-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) { 
        self.parentNode.alpha = self.parentNode.alpha - 0.1;
    } 
}

@end
```

В общем, как-то так :)

Comment: И снова не то :(
Просто -(void)motionBegan, написаный в сцене, никак не реагирует :(

Comment: Да, нужно сделать, чтобы SKScene удовлетворял какому-то там протоколу, нужно настроить делегат, все дела... Если честно, не сталкивался с акселерометром, не знаю точно, как там должно быть